# Set all highlight groups starting with a certain name?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

Basically I have a long list of highlight groups that start with `DevIcon` (`DevIconPng`, `DevIconJs` etc.), they all come with their own `ctermfg` and `guifg` and I would like to change them to a single color.

Something like:

`hi DevIcon* guifg=#123456 ctermfg=25`

Is this possible, or if not, is there some workaround?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`getcompletion()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getcompletion%28%29) function to resolve all highlights starting with a specific prefix. For example:

```
:echo getcompletion('DevIcon', 'highlight')
['DevIconPng', 'DevIconJs', ...]
```

You can then use that in a `for` loop to act on them.

```
:for hl in getcompletion('DevIcon', 'highlight') | execute 'hi '.hl.' guifg=#123456 ctermfg=25' | endfor
```

See [`:help :for`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Afor) and [`:help :execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute), also [`:help expr-.`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-.) for the string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! Just a minor correction (I tried to edit myself, but couldn't since it's a small change), there should be a space after `... .hl.'guifg=...` (should be `... .hl.' guifg=...`).

Comment: Sorry for the typo and thanks for spotting it! I have just fixed it myself now. Glad this worked for you!